# Neo4j - Finding the nearby node set

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, shortest-path

I would like to obtain a node close to a certain node using Neo4j.

[Techniques that take edge costs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_all_pairs_and_single_source_shortest_path) into account are popular, but the method using node cost is not.

For example, in [this sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxE3R.png), the nodes in the vicinity of node A are B, C, E, G, H, I.

- The total cost is within 15.
- The cost of A is not included.
- The edge direction can be ignored.

The minimum cost between nodes of the sample graph is expected as follows.

```
A<->B : 3
A<->C : 8
A<->D : 50
A<->E : 10
A<->F : 16
A<->G : 11
A<->H : 13
A<->I : 14
```

The sample graph can be created with the following query.

```
CREATE
(a:Node{name:"A",cost:10}),
(b:Node{name:"B",cost:3}),
(c:Node{name:"C",cost:5}),
(d:Node{name:"D",cost:50}),
(e:Node{name:"E",cost:10}),
(f:Node{name:"F",cost:8}),
(g:Node{name:"G",cost:1}),
(h:Node{name:"H",cost:2}),
(i:Node{name:"I",cost:1}),
(a)-[:Edge]->(b),
(b)-[:Edge]->(c),
(a)-[:Edge]->(d),
(a)-[:Edge]->(e),
(c)-[:Edge]->(f),
(d)-[:Edge]->(f),
(e)-[:Edge]->(g),
(g)-[:Edge]->(h),
(h)-[:Edge]->(i),
(f)-[:Edge]->(i);
```

In response to comments, [I rebuilt the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31iSJ.png). Added edge to calculate cost.

```
MATCH (n)-[]-(m)
MERGE (n)-[r:COST{cost:m.cost}]->(m)
```

And I executed the following query.

```
MATCH(startNode:Node{name:"A"}),(endNode:Node)
CALL algo.shortestPath(startNode, endNode, "cost",{relationshipQuery:'COST', defaultValue:1.0,write:false,direction:'OUTGOING'})
YIELD nodeCount, totalCost
WITH nodeCount, totalCost, endNode
WHERE totalCost <= 15
RETURN nodeCount, totalCost, endNode
ORDER BY totalCost ASC;
```

Then I got the results I expected.

```
╒═══════════╤═══════════╤══════════════════════╕
│"nodeCount"│"totalCost"│"endNode"             │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════════════════╡
│0          │-1         │{"name":"A","cost":10}│
├───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────┤
│2          │3          │{"name":"B","cost":3} │
├───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────┤
│3          │8          │{"name":"C","cost":5} │
├───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────┤
│2          │10         │{"name":"E","cost":10}│
├───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────┤
│3          │11         │{"name":"G","cost":1} │
├───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────┤
│4          │13         │{"name":"H","cost":2} │
├───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────┤
│5          │14         │{"name":"I","cost":1} │
└───────────┴───────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

However, when I executed a similar query in the database I actually use, I could not do it due to a huge amount of computation...

```
Failed to invoke procedure `algo.shortestPath`: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1340037571
```

Does anyone have an idea to search nearby node set efficiently?

Comment: Why not run a cypher query to update all incoming edges to the node and set the weight of the edge to be the weight of the node?  Then the standard edge-weighted approaches should work just as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I rebuilt the sample graph, it worked properly in the graph. However, the computational complexity has become enormous on the database that I actually want to apply... For details, look the edited questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this cypher query :

```
MATCH p=(start {name:"A"})-[r*..10]-(end {name:"I"})
RETURN reduce(x=0, n IN tail(nodes(p)) | x + n.cost) AS cost
ORDER BY cost ASC
LIMIT 1
```

But in this case, Neo4j will search all existing paths between `start` and `end`, then it will compute the global cost. So it's an expensive query ...

If you want performances, you should take a look a the implementation of the `algo.shortestPath` function from the graph-algo to create your own procedure/algo.